# How to create a nested dictionary from pandas dataframe and again convert it to dataframe?

Tags: pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {

    'Fruit':['Guava','Orange','Lemon'],
    'ID1':[1,2,11],
    'ID2':[3,4,12],
    'ID3':[5,6,np.nan],
    'ID4':[7,8,14],
    'ID5':[9,10,np.nan],
    'ID6':[11,np.nan,np.nan],
    'ID7':[13,np.nan,np.nan],
    'ID8':[15,np.nan,np.nan],
    'ID9':[17,np.nan,np.nan],
    'Category':['Myrtaceae','Citrus','Citrus']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
df
```

How to convert the above dataframe to the following dictionary.

Expected Output :

```
{
    'Myrtacease':{'Guava':{1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17}},
    'Citrus':{'Orange':{2,4,6,8,10,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan},{'Lemon':{11,12,np.nan,14,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan}},

}
```

How to again convert the dictionary to a dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use list comprehension with `groupby`:

```
d = {k: v.set_index('Fruit').T.to_dict('list') 
        for k, v in df.set_index('Category').groupby(level=0)}
print (d)
{'Citrus': {'Orange': [2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0, 10.0, nan, nan, nan, nan], 
            'Lemon': [11.0, 12.0, nan, 14.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]}, 
'Myrtaceae': {'Guava': [1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 7.0, 9.0, 11.0, 13.0, 15.0, 17.0]}}
```

Or:

```
d = {k: v.drop('Category', axis=1).set_index('Fruit').T.to_dict('list') 
             for k, v in df.groupby('Category')}
```

And then:

```
df = (pd.concat({k: pd.DataFrame(v) for k, v in d.items()}, axis=1)
       .T
       .rename_axis(('Category','Fruit'))
       .rename(columns=lambda x: f'ID{x+1}')
       .reset_index())

print (df)
    Category   Fruit   ID1   ID2  ID3   ID4   ID5   ID6   ID7   ID8   ID9
0     Citrus  Orange   2.0   4.0  6.0   8.0  10.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
1     Citrus   Lemon  11.0  12.0  NaN  14.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2  Myrtaceae   Guava   1.0   3.0  5.0   7.0   9.0  11.0  13.0  15.0  17.0
```

Comment: I have one more doubt?

Comment: @panda - Sure, what is problem?

Comment: @How to create dictionary without nan? I.e remove nan on the dictionary?

Comment: @panda - use `d = {k: v.drop('Category', axis=1).set_index('Fruit').T.dropna().to_dict('list') 
        for k, v in df.groupby('Category')}`

Comment: add `dropna` only

Comment: can you please check the chat?

Comment: are you there can you help?